# Cannot Download Image from URL in Mobile Devices Using Unity

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, download, textures, hosting

I am having trouble downloading pictures on my mobile devices.

I use this code for downloading down below:

```
public IEnumerator DownloadImageRaw(string MediaUrl, RawImage poster)
{
    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(MediaUrl);
    request.SendWebRequest();
    if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
    {
        poster.texture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("images/NoPoser");
        Debug.Log(request.error);
        yield break;
    }
    else
    {           
        poster.texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;
    }
}
```

Link A:https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZmVmYTE2OGEtMTkzOC00YzNiLTlhYWQtZDFiMmJiZDBmNTAwXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg

Link B:
http://www.subzerone.com/nfp/poser/1.jpg

if I use "Link A" for  MediaUrl, working in all devices (Unity Editor,Nox Player,My Mobile Phone).

But "Link B" just doesn't work on my mobile phone.

"Link B" Work perfect  on Unity Editor and Nox Player.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mobile devices require security exceptions or provisioning adjustments to be able to use `http`. Consider `https` instead or ask about how to possibly circumvent this on a specific type/version of device.

Comment: probably a bug.. it could be because of not having SSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is Unity 2018 Versions.

i upgraded my project 2019. problem is solved.